# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [720, 53]

Tags: testing, split, xgboost, feature-selection, lasso-regression

[image]
Can someone help me to solve this error?

> ValueError : Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
> samples : [720, 53]

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's pretty straighforward: you passed `X` and `y` of different shapes.

Features (`X`) and labels (`y`) should be of the same lenght in order to `train_test_split` to create proper datasets and to later fit the model to them.